# Langchain: modify prompt in callback

Tags: callback, langchain, large-language-model

I want to modify an LLM prompt at runtime by replacing some strings with user input.
The idea is to do that when the chain starts executing before it calls the LLM.
I tried creating a custom handler and implementing the 'on_chain_start' method.
The method signature is as follows:

`def on_chain_start( self, serialized: Dict[str, Any], inputs: Dict[str, Any], **kwargs: Any ) -> Any`

In `serialized['kwargs']['prompt']['kwargs']['template']` I can see the current prompt's template and I'm able to change it manually, but when the chain execution continues, the original prompt is used (not the modified one in the handler).

How can I change the prompt's template at runtime using the on_chain_start callback method?

Thanks.